# how to use local firewall ip from other internet devices

Tags: ip, vpn

i don't know about IP i want to know about any solution for my question ?

**question is**

i want to use my local firewall form other internet device with local fire wall ip?

**what was happens ?**

my `firewall ip is 46.256.215.56` (**this for example**) it will connected to my PC X `ip 198.122.123`(**this for example**).

if i access my web page with my PC X it will so ip is `46.256.215.56` and client ip is `ip 198.122.123`

but if i access this web page form my mobile with mobile internet it will so ip is `152.233.222`(**this for example**)

how to access 46.256.215.56 in other internet ip

**what i need ?**

if i access that web page form other internet or other device it have to show ip as `46.256.215.56`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your firewall is written, your device mobile device would need a key or to be written into the permissions in some aspect. For example if I wanted to connect to my firebase server or ip, I could go threw the web pages, or I could sign in with a terminal or command promp and establish connection. So Basically your server should have a permissions file you can edit for your mobile device, or you need to use your keypair and use some sort of terminal from the app store. Mobile devices are not very secure though so with a third party terminal app you may run into some security issues.